# i am getting below error while i am implementing the webpack in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui, yarn-v2

ERROR in ./src/index.js 9:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:2)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |
  | ReactDOM.render(

> <React.StrictMode>
> |     
> |   </React.StrictMode>,

index.js

```
import './index.css';

import App from './App';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```